Admin 2fa email not receiving
I don't get a email if I log in for the first time in the admin panel I made the admin account with cli

This is not a direct answer to your question, but if this is preventing you from getting into the admin panel, you could try disabling the 2FA modules as a workaround:
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_TwoFactorAuth
php bin/magento module:disable Magento_AdminAdobeImsTwoFactorAuth

Then to apply changes, run:
php bin/magento setup:upgrade 

That should get you into the admin panel with the username and password you created in the CLI
NOTE: This is definitely a security risk and is not a long term solution
